# Euclid theory problem on number theory for p divides the binomial coefficient.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

let p be a prime and let n be any integer satisfying 1<= n <= p-1. 
Prove that p divides the binomial coefficient
(p,n) = p!/[(p-n)!n!]

i know that p|p! but p does not divides 1/[(p-n)!n!] since 1/[(p-n)!n!] < p.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please LaTeX the questions you post here. LaTeX is very easy to learn and it makes everything much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $n<p$, then $p$ and $n$ are coprime as otherwise would mean that $p$ divides $n$, which is impossible as $p>n$. Next look at the denumerator of $\binom{p}{n}$. It is 
$n!(p-n)!$. The question you have to ask yourself is: does $p$ divide that.